# Cannot deploy the file on hosting: LocalStorage issue in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I found a perfectly working js library which contains the function I share in the end of the question. I downloaded the whole library to my own hosting, it works OK, but then I found that the file contains an outer link in that function to some txt file on 3-rd party site. I would like the code to work autonomously on my hosting. I just copy the code from `http://free-vpn.pro/stat/countryList.txt` file, create the same file on my own hosting and change the link. But then the whole script stops working. What am I doing wrong? Seems it's not enough to just copy it? It's very strange, the file is just a static txt...

```js
function getCountryList() {
    chrome.proxy.settings.clear({
        scope: "regular"
    }), countryList = $.get("http://free-vpn.pro/stat/countryList.txt?uid=" + localStorage.uid + "&ver=" + localStorage.version, function() {
        chrome.storage.local.get(localStorage.country, function(a) {
            if ("NOVPN" == localStorage.country) return void setProxy("", "direct");
            localStorage.country && "disabled" != a[localStorage.country].status ? setProxy(a[localStorage.country].url, "pac_script") : chrome.storage.local.get("NL", function(a) {
                setProxy(a.NL.url, "pac_script")
            })
        })
    }).fail(function() {
        $.getScript("default.js")
    }), (new Date).getTime() - localStorage.uid > 3e8 && 0 == localStorage.share && (localStorage.share = 1, onShared())
}
```

Extension manifest:

```js
{
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["lib/jquery/jquery.min.js", "bg.js", "ga.js"]
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "images/icon32.png",
        "default_popup": "lib/select/popup.html"
    },
 "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://ssl.google-analytics.com; object-src 'self'",
 "icons": {
  "256": "images/icon256.png",
  "128": "images/icon128.png",
  "48": "images/icon48.png",
  "32": "images/icon32.png",
  "16": "images/icon16.png"
 },
 "manifest_version": 2,
 "default_locale": "en",
 "name": "__MSG_name__",
 "short_name": "__MSG_short_name__",
 "description": "__MSG_description__",
 "permissions": ["tabs", "proxy", "storage", "webRequest", "webRequestBlocking", "webNavigation", "management", "\u003Call_urls>"],
 "update_url": "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",
 "version": "1.0.0"
}
```

Comment: What does the 3rd party library do?

Comment: @ScottMarcus it is a proxy server

Comment: What's in the extension manifest?

Comment: @ephemient I updated the question, please take a look at the manifest

Comment: I would expect `$.get` to be asynchronous and hence its return value is nothing useful. Async code is different: the result is available in the callback or in `.then()` for promisified code.